# I would like to stretch my HStack when the first row is "full"

Tags: swiftui

[image]

I'm trying to make a keywords list for my app like on this picture. I would like to stretch my HStack when the first row is "full" ...

What is the best way to do this ?

Here my code :

```
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .foregroundColor(.orange)

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(exercice.name)
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                ForEach(exercice.muscles ?? [], id: \.self) { muscle in
                    MuscleBadge(muscle: muscle)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you could implement a collection which takes views and uses two stacked `ForEach` and a geometry reader or sth to make as much as possible fit, but that would probably be too complicated and the performance.. no idea.

Comment: can you show us your `MuscleBadge(muscle: Muscle)` View?